# How to execute a DMV query in SSAS through a powershell runbook from Azure Automation?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, dmv, analysisservices, mdac

I am trying to open a **connection** with a **ssas server** and execute a **dmv query** in order to extract table metadata, through a **powershell runbook** from an **Azure Automation Account**.

I have already written and tested a powershell script that seems to **work fine** on my **local machine**, but when I run the same script on the **cloud** as an azure runbook it seems **impossible** to open a connection.

I used this **code** to open the connection with ssas:

```
 $connectionString = "Provider=msolap; Data Source=asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/servername;User Id={0};Password={1}; Initial Catalog=DataModel" -f $ssasUser, $ssasPassword;
    
 ## Connect to the data source and open SSAS
 $connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionString
 $connection.Open()
```

I can't seem to be able to open a connection, as I run this code I receive the following **error**:

```
 System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later."
```

Searching on the web, the only solution I found seems to be to simply download and install the MDAC sdk but this can't be done while running on the cloud.

I need help to **fix** this error or find an **alternative solution**.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find aleady a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As the source in the connection string is having asazure so I assume that it's an Azure Analysis server so I would recommend you to import SqlServer module in your Azure Automation account as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-refresh-azure-automation#sample-powershell-runbook) and then use [Invoke-ASCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-ascmd?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet in your runbook.

Related references:

- https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-automation-automate-pause-and-resume-of-azure-analysis-services/
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/automating-azure-analysis-service-processing-using-azure/ba-p/319006
- https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/industry-blog/en-gb/technetuk/2018/06/22/how-to-automate-processing-your-azure-analysis-services-models/
- https://jorgklein.com/2017/02/02/process-azure-analysis-services-databases-from-azure-automation/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0
- https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OledbSql/1.0.4